# Highlight specific row base on content in jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, datatables

I am using jquery datatables.net and I have a table with information. In the one column I have true or false values for whether the user is active or not. I am trying to get it so when the value is false, highlight the value. Right now my code for my table settings looks like this:

```
        //Settings for datatable
        $('#userTable').DataTable({
            "jQueryUI": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "type": "POST",
                url: "/Management/StaffGet",
                "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'data': function (data) { console.log(data); return data = JSON.stringify(data); }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "employeeNumber" },
                { "data": "firstName" },
                { "data": "lastName" },
                { "data": "role" },
                {
                    "data": "active",

                },
                {
                    "data": "employeeNumber",
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
                    {
                        return '<a href="/Management/Edit/' + data + '">Edit </a> &#124; <a href="/Management/Delete/' + data + '">Delete </a>';
                    }
                }
            ],
            "order": [[ 0, "asc"]],
            "paging": true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "processing": true,
            "stateSave": false,
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "pageLength": 10,
            "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
            "searching": false,
            "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
                if (data[4] == "false" ) {
                    $('td', row).eq(5).addClass('highlight');
                       }
                 }
        });`
```

Then my code for css is:

```
`<style type="text/css">
      td.highlight {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
     }
</style>`
```

I feel like there is a problem with the setting on the column, any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you inspect the td with your browser inspector, does it get the class of "highlight"?

Comment: no it doesn't. it doesn't show any instance of the 'highlight' for it

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(data[4])` right before your if statement: `if (data[4] == "false" ) {`?

Comment: the console is reading that the objects aren't defined

Comment: What if you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: yeah i did that. and it gives me the objects and says they are undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#userTable').DataTable({
...
"createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
    //console.log(data[4]);
    if ( data[4] == "false" ) {
            //console.log($(row).find("td").eq(4).html());
            $(row).find("td").eq(4).addClass( 'highlight' );
    }},
...
```

The commented log statements are in there to check you are getting and comparing the correct data.

Tested with datatables 1.10.1

Comment: Sorry for the late response - holiday away from the computer =) "createdRow" was added in datatables 1.10. Is updating a possibility?

Comment: i am currently using 2.1.4